# Auto-refresh IMPORT HTML function in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to get a script to work which I found online, which functions to refresh IMPORTHTML function:

```
https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/206260188-Using-Google-Sheets-IMPORTHTML-function-to-display-data-in-Geckoboard
```

So according to the script, the getdata function is supposed to create an HTML in a certain value (this part works for me) and afterwards I have to set a trigger for this function for every minute (this I did succesfully as well). However, the data I get in my spreadsheet is still not updated. Even after 5 minutes have gone by, nothing changes, when it is supposed to update my crypto currency price every minute. Please take a look at the sheet and let me know what I did wrong:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gjjpH7Y7S-OgKdKR6U-VXRnOkq34rCbz_U8Svp7rT-k/edit?usp=sharing
```

If you know an alternative way to auto-refresh HTML, please let me know. This was the best I could find. My goal is to auto-refresh a function which is dynamic such as in cell A20. Having a refresh rate of 15-20 minutes is fine as well but it has to be more often than it is right now!

Comment: I looked at your code, and you don't have any triggers setup in App Script.   Read this documentation on how to set up time based triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en#time-driven_triggers

Comment: So thank you for your comment. I read the website and tried the different triggers. However, still no success. Could you please look again and see what I did wrong? Tried to set it at every minute or through a script at every open, but doesn't seem to work either way.

Comment: It seems to be working.  I fixed the function that changes A20, you had it referencing C3 instead of C2.   Your triggers are working.  If you go to your code, click on the 4th icon down on the left side "Executions", and you can see everytime it ran.

Comment: Solution verified!

Comment: It does seem to work. Thanks a ton for your help!